# angular showing fixed number of items in a list with show more and show less buttons

Tags: angular, list, slice

I have a long list and I want to display only fixed number of items(say 5) . The list should grow bigger with the click of **showmore** button. when all the items on the list gets rendered **showless** button should appear. The showless button should be clickable until the list size becomes 5 again. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewencapsulation-qwnpff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
I would also like to show a transition of 0.5s when the list items gets added or removed from the list.

Comment: Why don't you use a library like https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yazantahhan. I don't want the scroll, I want the button click to show/hide the list.

Comment: Question: how can I count the number of displayed li items on the DOM?

Comment: You can have a variable that contains the rendered items. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let l of renderedList" dataRows>
  <li>{{l}}</li>
</ul>
<button *ngIf="buttonsVisibility.more" (click)="showMoreOrLess('more')"> show more</button>
<button *ngIf="buttonsVisibility.less" (click)="showMoreOrLess('less')"> showLess</button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("dataRows") shownRows;
  buttonsVisibility = {
    more: true,
    less: false
  };
  givenList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
  renderedList = this.givenList.slice(0, 5);
  counter = 1;
  renderedAllItems = false;

  showMoreOrLess(moreOrLess: "more" | "less") {
    if (moreOrLess === "more") {
      // No need to set anything of the rendered array contains all the items
      if (this.givenList.length / 5 + 1 === this.counter) {
        return;
      }
      this.counter++;
    } else {
      // If less, then decrease the counter, and if the counter got 0, then make it 1
      this.counter = --this.counter || 1;
    }
    // rendered list will be the counter * 5
    this.renderedList = this.givenList.slice(0, this.counter * 5);
    // This is a flag to show the less button once I got the end and keep showing it once it is true
    this.renderedAllItems =
      this.renderedAllItems ||
      this.renderedList.length === this.givenList.length;
    this.setButtonsVisibility();
  }

  setButtonsVisibility() {
    // Show more button while we didn't get the end
    this.buttonsVisibility.more =
      this.renderedList.length < this.givenList.length;
    // Show less button once I got the end or the renderedAllItems flag is true with the counter not 1 
    this.buttonsVisibility.less =
      this.renderedList.length === this.givenList.length ||
      (this.renderedAllItems && this.counter !== 1);
  }
}
```

You can play with the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-viewencapsulation-yc6wfs